# Report Builder - How to show upcoming month report

Tags: reporting-services

I am struggling to find a simple answer to what I think is a simple problem. I am making a report that shows expiring documents. I want to show documents that are expirering in the next month. The report will be ran the first and should show everything expiring that month. How do I format the group filter expression to show =Globals!ExecutionTime but for the whole month?

[View of my report in Design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9bKr.png)

I have spent hours looking into this and I expect a simple answer and I am not finding anything, even long answers.

Comment: Edit your question and show your current filter expression. Typically you would do this in the dataset query so that you only return the data you need rather than getting the report to filter the results of the dataset. Also, define what you mean by `whole month`, do you mean anything in the same month as the current month or anything in the past n days , or in the next n days etc? Normally I would do this in the query with something like `WHERE MONTH(myDateColumn) = MONTH(GetDate())` or something similar.